# Discord emoji removed and comes back

Tags: discord

I own a Discord server and am trying to remove an emoji.

There's an emoji that I removed a long time ago and it just came back today. 
There's no audit logs on it, and when I remove it, it pops back up every time.  How can I permanently remove the emoji?

I have banned the user who uploaded the emoji. There's no audit log of it being deleted/added; only the one time it was added a long time ago. I've had a friend delete it, restarted Discord and restarted my PC, but it is still there.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to actively select it fro new messages or are you just seeing it in old messages?

Comment: Sorry, not in messages.  I am trying to remove the emoji in server setting under Emoji.  From there, I click the Remove button and then the Emoji comes right back.  This typically just works.  Thanks!

Comment: Discord was having some server problems a few days ago. That could be related

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it what you have to do is delete one emoji at a time slowly like 30 secs in between every delete. So delete each emoji once every 30 secs.